# Partial update without retrieving the object from db

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am looking for some way to partially update an object without retrieving the object from DB.
Say I have an Employee entity containing the following properties -

1. firstName
2. lastName
3. phone
4. age
5. salary

The JSON I get in the update request may not contain all the properties. I need to make sure I update only the properties provided in the request and leave all other data unchanged.

I explored some ways of achieving partial update but all of them involves retrieving the data from db. I don't have this option since the db in my case is too slow and this will increase the response time. Please suggest

Comment: How you can update without a primary key?

Comment: You must get origin data from the database by a primary key which Employee is updating :
- Verify that the record you're trying to update is valid
- You will only update fields which present on the request body 
That a good approach

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `@Modifying` and `@Query` annotation to issue an update query

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Employee e set e.firstName = :firstName, e.lastName = :lastName where e.id = :id")
void updateEmployeePartially(Long id, String firstName, String lastName);
```

For more information, you can check this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-partial-update)

Comment: Where you get ID?

Comment: Thanks for notifying, I missed that while writing, I have edited my answer.